# JMH Micro Benchmark Annotations with Scala

Tags: scala, microbenchmark, jmh

I am a newbie to JMH. I don't really understand how it work after running my code and using different annotations.
I use iteration = 1, warmup = 1, fork =1 in order to see my code will be executed one time, but it's not. JMH run my code more than 100,000 times, and I don't know why. So, how can I control the number of time my code called?
Here is my code: (I fix JMHSample_01 for my test)

```
package org.openjdk.jmh.samples
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 1, time = 1)
@Fork(1)
class JMHSample_01_HelloWorld {

  @Benchmark
  def wellHelloThere(): Unit = {
    // this method was intentionally left blank.
    val a:Int =  1
    val b:Int = 2
    val c:Int = a + b
    println("this is c " + c)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how JMH works: it executes your code a dozen of times to find out what the average execution time is. A Java program needs to be run many times before the Java JIT-compiler optimizes a code. The benchmark tricks the JIT compiler to consider a benchmark method to be important in order to optimize it properly.

Your benchmark has many problems: it is deterministric where `1 + 2` is always `3` if this is what you want to measure: it will simply replace the computation with the end result.

Please [look at the JMH samples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/) to learn how to use JMH properly. In this context, it does not play much of a role that your benchmarks are written in Scala as it compiles down to Java byte code.

Comment: "a dozen of times" --> Can I control this? I mean I want it to be exact.

Comment: You can limit the amount of warmup and benchmark iterations but you should not rely on it.

Comment: Hi, do you know any detail document about JMH? JMH samples they do not explain detail. For example, using @Param, I do not know how to specify Param's elements in my def.  They just use underscore to specify elements. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can read through the examples linked in my answer; I would not know of another source of documentation. As for specifying parameters, there is an example linked however. I found the examples quite helpful as they get you going pretty quickly.

Comment: Hi, for example, I would like to run a function with a large range of parameters. If I use @Param of JMH, I need to specify an Array of String of parameters. I try to specify a constant outside and plug it in Param. But it cannot recognize.

Comment: You can also set parameters programatically via the optionsbuilder.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me one example or any link about it? Thank you a lot. I am just a novice

Comment: Have a look at `org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder` where a `params` method is defined. You can name the field and its values there.